# Unexpected result in PHP stacked ternary operator

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I am using PHP to try to get a percentage by dividing one number by another. However if either number is falsey, the default result should be 0.0. I'm using a ternary operation to determine what the result. However, it appears to default to the last calculation, which clearly equates to a divide by zero error. Any ideas?

The code:

```
$countOne = 3;
$countTwo = 0;
echo (! $countOne || ! $countTwo) ? 'true' : 'false';

$number =
    (! $countOne || ! $countTwo) ?
        0.0 :
            ($countOne > $countTwo) ?
                $countTwo / $countOne :
                    $countOne / $countTwo;

echo $number;
```

I'll use an if statement for now, but I can't see why the above wouldn't work.

TEST: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83f737ab27fb046a8eb9feb4992d5dd26340723d

Comment: That looks really ugly, why don't you split it up?

Comment: if you're wanting to check for boolean `true/false`, remove the quotes for one thing. Otherwise, they are strings; is that what you're checking for?

Comment: `10 / 5` is not the same as `5 / 10` so switching them around if one is > makes no sense. are you simply trying to prevent division by 0 error?

Comment: Sorry, strings are just a test. I have added a PHP sandbox, so you can see the result....

Comment: @LawrenceCherone correct. The result doesn't matter as much as preventing a divide by zero error.

Comment: `$countTwo = 0`, `$countOne / $countTwo` ... ?

Comment: Then just do `echo $countTwo === 0 ? $countOne : $countOne / $countTwo;`

Comment: This if statement works and is tidier, so I'll use that, but I don't see why the ternary statement wouldn't work. `if(! $sourceWordCount || ! $searchedWordCount)
       $percentage = 0.0;
       
      elseif ($sourceWordCount > $searchedWordCount)
       $percentage = $searchedWordCount / $sourceWordCount;
       
      else
       $percentage = $sourceWordCount / $searchedWordCount;`

Comment: Try putting everything after `0.0 :` in `()`.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone if `$countOne` isn't zero, result should be zero.

Comment: @NicoHaase you're right it is ugly. I guess I just like ternary's and hate if's. I've just changed to an if and it works fine. Plus it's easier to read. 

Comment: Then use this `echo $countOne !== 0 || $countTwo === 0 ? 0 : $countOne / $countTwo;`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone really sorry, should have said result must be less than 1.

Comment: `echo ($v = $countOne !== 0 || $countTwo === 0 ? 0 : $countOne / $countTwo) < 1 ? 0 : $v;` so many ways to skin a cat in 1 line ;p

Comment: If `$countOne` has to be `0` then you might as well do `echo 0;` as `0/10` is still `0` regardless of the original problem. Good luck moving on, the goal post has moved.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone many, many thanks for your input. See accepted answer for as to why my statement didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many years ago, the creator of PHP made a mistake which is now too late to fix, resulting in an unhelpful "associativity" of the ternary operator, which is described in a note on [the manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

> It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious:
>
> ... this is because ternary expressions are evaluated from left to right

So when you wrote this:

```
$number =
    (! $countOne || ! $countTwo) ?
        0.0 :
            ($countOne > $countTwo) ?
                $countTwo / $countOne :
                    $countOne / $countTwo;
```

You expected it to be understood by PHP as:

```
$number =
    (
        (! $countOne || ! $countTwo) 
            ? 0.0
            : (
                ($countOne > $countTwo)
                    ? $countTwo / $countOne
                    : $countOne / $countTwo
               )
    );
```

That is, perform the first test, then either give the final result `0.0`, or proceed to the second test.

But PHP actually understands it as:

```
$number =
    (
        (! $countOne || ! $countTwo) 
            ? 0.0
            : ($countOne > $countTwo)
    )
    ? $countTwo / $countOne
    : $countOne / $countTwo;
```

In other words, the whole first `... ? ... : ...` expression is evaluated first, and when the second one runs, it's working with one of these three possibilities:

```
 $number = 0.0 ? $countTwo / $countOne : $countOne / $countTwo;
 $number = true ? $countTwo / $countOne : $countOne / $countTwo;
 $number = false ? $countTwo / $countOne : $countOne / $countTwo;
```

All of these will evaluate either `$countTwo / $countOne` or `$countOne / $countTwo`, so risk triggering the division by zero error.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem of Operator Precedence.

Of course I should tell that this is not very clean code. Anyway
Try to use parentheses after semicolons in alternative option;

```
$number =
    (!$countOne || !$countTwo) ?
        0.0 :
            (($countOne > $countTwo) ?
                $countTwo / $countOne :
                    $countOne / $countTwo);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is that PHP handles ternary operator associativity differently than you might expect. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php):

```
// ternary operator associativity differs from C/C++
$a = true ? 0 : true ? 1 : 2; // (true ? 0 : true) ? 1 : 2 = 2
```

Thus your expression gets computed as

```
((! $countOne || ! $countTwo) ? 0.0 : ($countOne > $countTwo)) ?
   $countTwo / $countOne : $countOne / $countTwo;
```

=>

```
0.0 ? $countTwo / $countOne : $countOne / $countTwo;
```

=>

```
$countOne / $countTwo
```

hence you get the divide by 0 error. You need to manually group the second operator to make it work properly i.e.

```
(! $countOne || ! $countTwo) ?
        0.0 :
            (($countOne > $countTwo) ?
                $countTwo / $countOne :
                    $countOne / $countTwo);
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thx mate.